# Regex for Sqlite Date Time

Tags: java, regex, sqlite, date

I want to check the format of a String with regex. It must match the following formats:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
- YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS

My current solution is this:

```
\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}( |T)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d{3})?
```

Actual i test it with this:

- 2016-11-15 12:12:12.123
- 2016-11-15T12:12:12.123
- 2016-11-15 12:12:12123
- 2016-11-15 12:12:12.
- 2016-11-15 12:12:12
- 2016-11-15T12:12:12

but it matches all. I test it with regex101.com.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: *I test it with regex101.com* - this is not a good reason to post a question if something does not work in a regex tester, especially the one that does not fully support the target environment regex flavor. What happens if you test in Java with `String#matches()`? Won't the regex work for you then? `s.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}( |T)\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}(\\.\\d{3})?")`